# Distributed Version Control System

Tags: version-control, distributed

I want to implement distributed version control system with my fellow programmers. They are scattered around. All using different IDEs or no IDEs/ different operating systems too. I'm new to the whole scenario.
Also, we have no root permission of our server, so we cannot use the server. 
How to go about it? What client side tool should I use preferably with a GUI. 
And how to implement it with a server or web hosting site?

Comment: Github lives in the clouds and will give you a free account for open source projects.  It works with Git.

Comment: I guess you want to use distributed version control system instead of implementing it, right ? BTW, What language are you guys using ?

Comment: @Jeff Li We will be working on multiple languages across multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to:

- run a virtual machine-like image (like Docker, [without needing root](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1034), which should be [possible soon](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2918))
- install in it a [Bitnami stack](http://bitnami.com/learn_more) like the [GitLab Bitnami one](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab).

You would get a GitHub-like clone instantly.