# what is the meaning of "Distributed" word in "Distributed Version Control System" like Git?

Tags: git, distributed-system

I have already  read the question [Distributed Version Control System](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18845337/1624792) to find the answer, but this question is different and arises while comparing "Distributed Version Control System" with other "Distributed Systems".

When I see word "Distributed" in other terms like "Distributed Database", "Distributed Cache" and "Distributed Computing" then I find that data or computing is really distributed over the network. Here the "Distributed" word means "Divided (*equally* not always)". For example in Hazelcast a "Distribute Cache system" the keys are really divided among provided nodes. But I do not find this similarity in "Distributed Version Control System".

1. Does Distributed means Divided in "Distributed Version Control System"?
2. If YES then what is Distributed (Because I do not see the division in code or commit history)?

Comment: The word "Distributed" here basically means "without enforcing the use of a central server". Not sure this constitutes a good and complete answer so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen So that means the whole repository is Distributed and no further dependency on the central server, except if you want to contribute back to central server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+distributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to version control systems, "distributed" is just the antonym for "centralized".  A Centralized Version Control System has a single central or master server.  It may or may not have additional servers, but if it *does* have additional servers and if those servers disagree with the designated central server, then those servers are *wrong:* the central server is the source of truth.  In a distributed version control system, there is no such server: all repositories are peers, at least from a design point of view.  Any system with a distributed design can, of course, be used *as if* it were centralized.  One can *use* Git in this fashion by designating one of the Git repositories as the main repository for updates.

> When I see word "Distributed" in other terms like "Distributed Database", "Distributed Cache" and "Distributed Computing" then I find that data or computing is really distributed over the network. Here the "Distributed" word means "Divided (equally not always)". For example in Hazelcast a "Distribute Cache system" the keys are really divided among provided nodes. But I do not find this similarity in "Distributed Version Control System".

Distributed databases with replication do not necessarily *divide* their storage.  For instance, [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) uses the [quorum system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum_(distributed_computing)) to elect a leader; all members of the quorum attempt to keep their copies of the data up to date.  Cache behavior in multi-processor systems is often a form of distributed storage as well, though generally considerably more tightly coupled.  See, e.g., the [Wikipedia entry for cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence).  Distributed systems with replication can be generally classified via [consistency models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model).

(A quick search suggests that Hazelcast has backups to handle node failure, so they must use some kind of consistency model as well.  If some subset of data in a distributed system is stored solely on a single node, those data become unavailable if the node fails.  Since the probability of failure generally increases with an increase in the number of nodes, this is usually not acceptable.)